# Making an RPM which sets POSIX files capabilities

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec, linux-capabilities

How does one make an [RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) which sets the [POSIX capabilities](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) of a file?  If I try doing `rpmbuild` as a non-root user then I get an error when my makefile's install hooks try to run [`setcap`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap), but if I don't run `setcap` how will  `rpmbuild` copy the capabilities?  There doesn't seem to be any way to set the capability from within the [RPM spec file](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There *is* a spec file macro for setting capabilities, `%caps`; for some reason this seems to be mainly documented in the [release notes](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.7.0#POSIX.1edraft15filecapabilities) and changelogs, so it took a while for me to find it.

It's used like this in the spec file:

```
%caps(cap_net_admin=pe) %{_sbindir}/foobar
```

To get `make install` to use `setcap` only when invoked by root, you can do something like this:

```
@if test `id -u` -eq 0; then \
    setcap cap_net_admin=pe $(DEST_SBINDIR)/foobar ; \
fi
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get the `%caps` directive to work. Was getting `syntax error near unexpected token \`cap_net_raw+ep'`. Found another solution using `%post` as described in this issue: https://github.com/schweikert/fping/issues/24#issue-5647305

Comment: Hopefully undocumented for [not too much longer](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2832).